# Is it possible or even logical to download an executable from SQL server via .NET?

Tags: c#, sql, memorystream

I am in the beginning stages of developing a solution to decrypt the hard drives of a few thousand laptops.

I have a thought that it would be useful to create a parent application that would handle all of the database calls, client updates, client commands and status updates. This application would either run as a service or as a .EXE from the computers start up.

Then have a child application perform all of the decryption and verification duties with logging to a XML file.

It is the child that I am thinking may need to be updated in the event new functionality is needed. That is where I am trying to think of the most logical way of updating it, my first thought went to storing it in SQL as a BLOB, and then pulling it down from the parent application if needed.

Does this sound reasonable? One item to note is that my target computers are all at .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible? Probably. Recommended? Probably not.

Is there any reason why you can't store the executable on a file share and have an entry in the database which points to a UNC path for the client to collect the file itself.

The file share is best for serving files so use it as such.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I see the value in using a file share, just was thinking outside the box on the SQL idea.

Answer (score 6):

Ms. SQL Server 2008 introduces FILESTREAM storage which gives you both the benefit from DBMS and speed of Filesystem. Worth having a look at it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the information about the FILESTREAM storage idea, unfortunely I do not believe that I can use it in a .NET 2.0 application. I beleive that .NET 2.0 framwork will not have that SQL data type.